# TypeError: a is undefined in my Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I cleaned up my code but now when I run it I am getting the following error

```
TypeError: a is undefined
```

I am not sure where it is coming from since it was working before I added the nested view and did not change the controller. Here is my code in [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/vN06ZQYWW0cpO4izBtgT?p=info). Let me know if there is anything else you need.

Comment: What file/line is reported to cause this error? Post the contents of just that file here.

Comment: This is the error as it appears in my console `TypeError: a is undefined
...ltPrevented};m(a[e||c.type],function(a){a.call(b,c)});Z<=8?(c.preventDefault=nul...  angular.min.js (line 23, col 355)`

Comment: I would recommend replacing angular.min.js with the full angular.js, errors like `a is undefined` are a product of minification.  using the full library will give you an idea of what `a` actually represents.

Comment: also, Angular.js 1.0.7 is nearly 2 years old, is there some reason that you aren't using 1.3?

Comment: I actually updated to angular.js 1.3.9 and now I get this error `TypeError: eventFns[i] is undefined      angular.js (line 3011, col 8)`

Comment: the error isn't exhibiting in your plunkr; are you using some sort of minification in your production code?

Comment: You are right. I updated the code adn while is working not all of it is working. Thank you guys here is the update [plunkr](http://embed.plnkr.co/FO7MurVc7oo1l4mwCTti/preview)

Answer (score -1):

I think you need this:

```
var gameApp = angular.module('guessGameApp');
```

at the top of  your maincontroller.js

Comment: Actually this is defined in the app.js file.